# Область действия сервисов

Tags: php, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Не могу понять правильную область действия сервисов в web приложении.
Вот у нас есть сервис, логично, как мне кажется, предположить, что его можно обернуть в другой класс, добавлять обсерверы, или стратегии. Возможно выполнять действия в зависимости от привилегий. Но где делать всё это? Это же уровнем выше сервиса, но при этом логика приложения - значит это не зона действий контроллера.

У меня в голове 2 выбора, а вы как считаете?

1. Делать ещё один слой между сервисом и контроллером. Но пока нигде такое не встречал, но и опыта у меня мало. Везде вижу controller-service-repository.
2. Делать дополнительные методы в сервисе, которые используют другие методы. Например есть метод `getById()` внутри которого происходит `notify()`. Но ведь обсерверы надо ещё забить в класс. Значит нужно ещё делать метод `SetObserversForGetById`? Ну это же вроде бред.

   Ещё интереснее, если взять ситуацию, что один метод вызывается в разных местах с разным количеством наблюдателей.
   Ну или делать `attach($observer)` в контроллере...

Comment: Никто вам не запрещает ввести ещё один уровень абстракции. Никто же не видел вашей задачи.

Comment: лучше описать задачу подробнее, желательно с каким нибудь примером. Что есть сервис? как вы добавляете обсерверы или стратегии? "Уровень выше сервиса" - какие в вашем приложении есть уровни? "не зона действий контроллера" - что есть контроллер в вашем приложении?

Comment: Приложение - это блог. Архитектура MVC, но где модель разделена на два слоя: логика - это сервисы, работа с БД - репозитории.